# AWS service for storing static files used by CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services

Which of the following AWS services is more suitable for storing static files used by a CDN that are accessed frequently?

EC2
S3
Glacier
ElastiCache
RDS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Simple Storage Service` AKA `S3`. Add a `CloudFront` distribution in front of it. For better security, use `Pre-Signed` URLs.

Answer (score 4):

This is a general question, so I am going to give a general answer. I would highly recommend reading the documentation for each of these AWS services.

S3: https://aws.amazon.com/s3/
EC2: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/
Glacier: https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/
ElastiCache: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/
RDS: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

All of these could be used to some extent (though ineffectively), but the use case you describe is what **S3** does best. Good luck!